# React Native setState will render JSX Element

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have two text input and one button

when I click the button, it will change its color

like

[image]

My question is when I click the button (setState)

only JSX-Element will render and TextInput will be cleared

(input)

[image]

(click)

[image]

How can I use JSX-TextInput and avoid this situation

code-example
https://snack.expo.dev/@tsaihenry/add958

Comment: As per your code `TextElement` is a function which returns a JSX.Element.  So change `<TextElement />` to `{TextElement()}` which will render the JSX element returned by the function. With that the input won't be cleared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your code `TextElement` is a function which returns a JSX.Element. So change `<TextElement />` to `{TextElement()}` which will render the JSX element returned by the function. With that the input won't be cleared.

```
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>

       <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="useless placeholder"
      />

      {TextElement()}
      
      <Button
        title="Press me"
        onPress={pressAgree}
        color = { (agree) ? "#f194ff" : "#94fff1"}
      />

    </View>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use controlled input field. Controlled component will behave as per as your state. It will clear input fields whenever you will press the button.

```js
const [textValue, setTextValue] = useState("");


  const pressAgree = () => {
    setAgree(!agree);
    setTextValue("");
  }

 <TextInput
        value={textValue}
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="useless placeholder"
      />

       <Button
        title="Press me"
        onPress={pressAgree}
        color = { (agree) ? "#f194ff" : "#94fff1"}
      />
```